# Finish or Exit the application from secondary activity?

Tags: java, android, systemexit

I am navigating the Activity 2, and by the time I press the back button, it should exit or finish the application without displaying the main activity. I am using ViewPager(Activity2), the code is working in `backpress` if I only navigate in the **first page** of the ViewPager, the moment I **navigate the other pages**, the code for exiting or finishing the application doesn't work and displays the mainActivity.

**MainActivity**

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
```

**Activity2**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
      super.onBackPressed();
    this.finish();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    System.exit(0);
    getParent().finish();
    Activity a1 = (Activity)this.getBaseContext();

    if(this.getParent()!=null){
        Activity a = (Activity)this.getParent().getApplicationContext();
        a.finish();
    }

    Log.i("Backpressed", "pressed");

}
```

Comment: You should not use `System.exit(0)` or exit the app. Clicking back button should take to the previous activity.

Use Actionbar on click of app icon navigate to home screen. click back button to exit app

Comment: I am not sure, if it gets called. Please don't downvote if you can't help improve my question.

Comment: i din't downvote and i don't understand "I am not sure, if it gets" called

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813717/android-application-exit-for-home-screen here it is already answered , Take some help from there.

Comment: @lordzden I downvoted, because this has been widely discussed in [SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow.com%3A+finish+activity+android),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work,

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Do this code on your `BackButton` of layout and also on `onBackPressed()` which is override method..it will surely work..:)

Comment: Thank you. Its better ,  instead of  calling  finish();

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that after "System.exit(0);" is called, the rest of the code will get called? as i remember, it won't. it should work as you wanted though.

anyway, please don't use any of those methods. the System.exit might be enough for you on some cases, but it in fact kills all of the threads of the app and considered a dirty way to do it.

instead, call startActivityForResult from Activity 1 to Activity 2 . then, in activity 2 call finish and set the result to something,  and on activity 1 check if the result is to exit the app, and if so, call finish() there too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this `android:noHistory="true"` into your manifest like this

```
<activity
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:name="com.example.activities.MainPageActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `finish();` in your MainActivity.
You can also Add the below lines in you Manifest under MainActivity

```
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
        android:noHistory="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using kill process..then on backpresses kill all the process..use a for loop to get pid for all the processes..and kill them..like this

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> list = am
            .getRunningAppProcesses();


    if (list != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
            String processid = list.get(i).processName;


            String packageName = mContext.getPackageName();
            if (processid.contains(packageName + ":homescreen")) {
                //here homescreen is the name you given in manifest for android:process

                Process.killProcess(list.get(i).pid);

            }
```

and in manifest for each activity add android:process=":anyname" like this

android:process=":homescreen"