# Preventing a KeyEvent system close highlighting an app

Tags: android, kotlin, keyevent

I currently have an app using a remote keyboard that when the 0 button is pressed it closes out the app. However when the app closes it highlights the first app on the home screen. Is there a way to prevent this? I have provided an example of the code I am using

```
override fun onKeyUp(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
            return when (keyCode) {
                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0 -> {
                    finish()
                    true
                    }
                else -> super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)
                }
            }
```

EDIT: Changed to more up to date code

Comment: I think finish() is appropriate way to exit an app. System.exit() should not be used to exit the app. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12813807/11377112)

Comment: Good shout, thank you. I'll check if this makes any difference to my situation in a bit.

Comment: Unfortunately made no difference